# image returned by UIImagePickerViewController not displayed

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I wrote the simplest iPhone application.  It has a single view window.  This main view contains an image view and 2 buttons, labeled "Picture from library" and "Take picture".  The application brings an image according to the selected button and makes it the image for the `UIImageView`.   The code to get the image is the following:

```
- (void) onCapturePicture:(BOOL)fromLibrary
{
    UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [controller setDelegate: self];
    [controller setSourceType: fromLibrary ? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary : UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [controller setAllowsEditing: YES];
    [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
    [self setImagePickerController: controller];
}
```

The delegate function where the image is returned and assigned to the `UIImageView` control is the following:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *pickedImage = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];   

    [_pictureView setImage: pickedImage];
    [[self view] setNeedsDisplay];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

I have tried also with `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` with the same results, which are:  when the picture comes from the photo library, it displays fine as the image in the `UIImageView`.  When the picture is captured using the camera it does not display at all, even though the pointer to the returned image is not nil.   If I use

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
         didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image 
                   editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
```

instead, everything works as expected, but the documentation indicates it's deprecated, and I guess it can be a reason for my app to get rejected.

Plus, I have 2 other questions related to the topic:

1. The `UIPickerController` takes a long time to show up the first time it's invoked when picking a picture from the photo library (like 11 secs).  Is there a way to reduce this loading time with some trick? (preloading silently on idle time or something)?
2. As soon as the camera opens, the application gets a memory warning (Received memory warning. Level=1).  Is there a way to avoid it, or am I doing something wrong?  This is a plain vanilla application with 2 buttons.  Basically 90% of the code I typed for this application is listed in this posting.  Just opening the camera is causing this to happen.  How can I avoid this problem?  I read other postings about memory leaks in `UIImagePickerController`, but that does not apply in this case.  I get the memory warning the first time I execute the code to get a picture with the camera.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to change these lines:

```
[[self view] setNeedsDisplay];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

to:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

As I don't believe you need to refresh the display.  I'm suggesting you change the dismissal method simply because I tested it and it works.  Good luck.